# Eclipse can't remember included "Android Library Projects"

Tags: android, eclipse, projects

I have several Android Projects marked as "Library Projects". I also have several Projects which use them, obviously.

The problem is, sometimes if I restart eclipse, all those Classes used from Library Projects are marked as "Not Found" and I can't quickfix that (using imports, etc.)

The only way I can fix it is right-click the project which includes library projects, remove all library projects, apply, then add them again. That is REALLY annoying, and I'd like to fix this permanently.

The Projects are using Android Library Projects and are not Library projects themselves. Eclipse Version: 3.7.1 Build id: M20110909-1335

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your Eclipse ADT plugin to the 15.0.1 release that shipped earlier this week. After one last fixup using the steps you outlined above, I haven't had a recurrence of this problem.